# How to force 64-bit LMDB to generate a 32-bit database?

Tags: c++, c, linux, build, lmdb

The executable  which uses the lmdb library is in 64 bit linux format .

Because  dependency libraries of the executable are in 64 bit .Building executable & lmdb lib as 32bit solution not possible.

Is there any way i can force 64 bit lmdb lib to generate a 32 bit lmdb database.

I need this 32 bit database file because the generated db will be exported to a 32 bit device.

Note : db generated on 64bit machine will not work on 32 bit machine.

Comment: Are you allowed to recompile the executable?

Answer (score 5):

I guess, the usage of a 64 bit database on a 32 bit lmdb is hard til impossible due to the fact, that lmdb is based on memory-mapping.

Thus, a converter would be necessary requiring the understanding of the underlying data format. This link [The LMDB file format](https://blog.separateconcerns.com/2016-04-03-lmdb-format.html) seems to be a good start for this.

A cheap alternative seems to be to dump the file on the 64 bit platform ([`mdb_dump`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/mdb_dump.1.html)) and to reload it on the 32 bit platform ([`mdb_load`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/mdb_load.1.html)). Though, this causes limitations as pointed out in the linked man page:

> Dumping and reloading databases that use user-defined comparison functions  will result in new databases that use the default comparison functions. **In this case it is quite likely that the reloaded database will be damaged beyond  repair permitting neither record storage nor retrieval.**

However, during searching the internet, I somewhere read that this can be used to port a 32 bit DB to 64 bit. I can only suspect that it should work the opposite way also (as I've never seen the format). As the dump is a text format, it should be possible – may be with an intermediate text processing step.

Another, IMHO rather cheap alternative, would be to run a 32 bit lmdb on the 64 bit platform. As I know that is common and usual on Windows, I was not (fully) sure for Linux and found this: [SE: How to run 32-bit app in Ubuntu 64-bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit). Unfortunately, the questioner stated that it is not an option in this specific case.